# Windows: subprocess.call ffmpeg triggers a WinError 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, subprocess

In Pycharm, I have correctly set up an environment with ffmpeg: the project interpreter C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe contains, among others, the package ffmpeg. I can see that in the menu Settings then Project then Project Interpreter.

I would want to use this environment when I execute the following command, so ffmpeg will be found and execute correctly:

```
subprocess.call(
        ['ffmpeg', '-i', 'XYZ/XYZ.webm', '-stream_loop', '-1', '-i', 'XYZ/XYZ.wav',
         '-c:v', 'copy', '-shortest', '-fflags', '+shortest', '-max_interleave_delta', '100M',
         'XYZ/XYZ.webm']
        , cwd='C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/ytg2/')
```

For the moment, however, the following error is triggered:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/ytg2/main.py", line 497, in 
> , cwd='C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/ytg2/')   File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 323, in call
> with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:   File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 775, in **init**
> restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 1178, in _execute_child
> startupinfo) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

What should I do?

Comment: The error message seems to be saying `ffmpeg` is not installed or not on your `PATH`, in French.

Comment: Well why is it set by Pycharm in the menu?

Comment: Because it sees a different `PATH`? Pure speculation; I don't use PyCharm, or Windows.

Comment: mmh would you know how to set the path of the env set by Pycharm? a priori not?

Comment: At least for debugging, you can `import os` and examine `os.environ['PATH']` in your script. If indeed it is incorrect, you can hardcode the path to `ffmpeg` (which by now you should know, even if you aren't revealing it) or maybe pass an augmented path to `subprocess,call()`,

Comment: Also this seems vaguely relevant: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006514380-using-system-PATH-variable-in-PyCharm

Comment: I'm vaguely guessing you have a Python package named `ffmpeg` which is displayed by PyCharm which is basically urelated to the external binary program `ffmpeg`. If the package is any good, you should probably use that instead of running the `ffmpeg` binary as a subprocess. Compare to using `subprocess.call(['echo'])` vs Python's built-in `print`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by downloading ffmpeg for windows (https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). I unzipped it in a folder. Then I changed my `subprocess call`:

```
subprocess.call(
        ['C:/Users/XYZ/Downloads/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe', '-i', 'XYZ/XYZ.webm', '-stream_loop', '-1', '-i', 'XYZ/XYZ.wav',
         '-c:v', 'copy', '-shortest', '-fflags', '+shortest', '-max_interleave_delta', '100M',
         'XYZ/XYZ.webm']
        , cwd='C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/ytg2/')
```

Note the `'C:/Users/XYZ/Downloads/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'`. Now, it works.